# SQL complex grouping "in column"

Tags: sql, grouping, calculated-columns

I have a table with 3 columns (sorted by the first two):

- letter
- number (sorted for each letter)
- difference between current number and previous number of the same letter

I'd like to calculate (with vanlla SQL) a **fourth new column RESULT** to group these data when the third column (difference of number between contiguos record; i.e #2 --> 4 = 5-1) is greater than 30 marking all the records of this interval with letter-number of the first record (i.e A1 for #1,#2,#3).

Since the difference between contiguos numbers makes sense just for records with the same letter, for the first record of a new letter, the value of differnce is 31 (meaning that it's a new group; i.e. #6).

Here is what I'd like to get as result:

```
#     Letter      Number      Difference             RESULT (new column)
1     A           1           1                      A1       
2     A           5           4                      A1
3     A           7           2                      A1
4     A           40          33                     A40       (*)
5     A           43          3                      A40       
6     B           1           31                     B1        (*)
7     B           25          24                     B1
8     B           27          2                      B1
9     B           70          43                     B70       (*)
10    B           75          5                      B70
```

Now I can only find the "breaking values" (*) with this query where they get a value of 1:

```
select letter
      ,number
      ,cast(difference/30 as int) break
 from table
where cast(difference/30 as int) = 1
```

Even though I'm able to find these breaking values I can't finish my task.

Can anyone help me finding a way to obtain the column RESULT?

Thanks in advance

FF

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Spark Sql (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), so I need the "most standard" SQL possible since most of "third party" constructs are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some exercise and a little help from a friend of mine, I've found a possible solution to my sql prolblem.

The only requirment for the solution is that my first record must have a value of 31 in Difference field (since I need "breaks" when Difference > 30 than the previous record).

Here is the query to get the column RESULT I needed:

```
select alls.letter
      ,alls.number
      ,ints.letter||ints.number as result
  from competition.lag alls
      ,(select letter
              ,number
              ,difference
              ,result 
          from (select letter
                      ,number
                      ,difference
                      ,case when difference>30 then 1 else 2 end as result
                  from competition.lag
               ) temp
         where result = 1
       ) ints
 where ints.letter=alls.letter
   and alls.number>=ints.number
   and alls.number-30<=ints.number
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to construct the last result column. You can use concat to do that:

```
 SELECT letter
          ,number
          ,concat(letter, cast(difference/30 as int)) result
     FROM table
    HAVING result = 'A1'
```

Comment: I'm not sure that what your code could work:
1) there's no aggregation function (for group by)
2) anyway, you could only get 3 records with (*) (the ones I called breaking values).

I need a "full" column like the one called Result

Comment: your second suggestion does not consider the fact that every record in a interval MUST have a "reference" to first one of that interval.
For example the first 3 records in my example MUST have the SAME value for the column result